# How to authenticate user with mobile number and otp ionic framework app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating an app using ionic framework. I want to authenticate user through OTP. I searched on google but didn't found any solutions . In ionic framework documents they mentioned oauth and signup .
Please help me out to find solutions for the same.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: I need to know that you need to pass OTP via SMS??

Comment: user will enter their mobile no and sms will be sent to their mobile no

Comment: Then you need to  buy SMS gateway for sending SMS. After User registration, You need to send OTP SMS through an SMS gateway for Registered user  from your server.

Comment: After that take input for OTP from user or read automatically and navigate to next step.

Comment: i want to when user come first time on my app he just enter their mobile no and got otp then enter otp after sucess user registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question on how to authenticate user the user through OTP through SMS you can easily do so by using a service like

https://sendotp.msg91.com/

The API is [very simple](https://sendotp.msg91.com/doc) and you can just send a http request to them to check. But I would advise to have a backend that communicates to the service instead of your Ionic app connecting to send OTP directly.

The hard route you could try would be for you to create the service by yourself in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AccountKit by Facebook which is completely free for Android, IOS and Web.
More detail here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit